# Use of "as ..., so ..." in negative forms

Tags: sentence

Is this sentence OK?

***As*** fish can't live without water, ***so*** can't people live without air. (1)

Or should I make some changes:

***As*** fish can't live without water, ***neither*** can people live without air. (2)

Fish can't live without water, ***nor*** can people live without air. (3)

People ***can't*** live without air ***any more than*** fish can live without water. (4)

Do sentences 2, 3, and 4 maintain the same meaning as that of the first?

Comment: Neither, neither … nor and not … either  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either_2

Comment: Sentence 2 sounds wrong, but I can't articulate why. In sentences 3 and 4, the meaning of the original sentence is not retained because the two statements are no longer connected by the implied "because".

Comment: @Noah So sentence 1 is ok?

Comment: @Noah Sentence 2 sounds OK to me. I think all the examples are acceptable and have basically the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence (1) sounds awkward because the two sentences have the same lexical verb *live*. Typically the lexical verb is left out of the *so...* part if it is the same as the the one in the *as...* part. It could be changed to:

> As fish can't live without water, so can't people without air.

The subject-auxiliary inversion is also optional in the *so...* part, and the sentence seems to read better without it, even if the lexical verb is repeated.

> As fish can't live without water, so people can't (live) without air.

As for (2), the *so* from (1) is optional in these constructions (CaGEL p1539), so removing it is a valid choice. *Neither* is a connective adjunct in clause structure that triggers subject-auxiliary inversion(CaGELp 1308) appearing in constructions like:

> If you don't complain, then *neither* will I.

This would keep the *as...* part as an adjunct of manner and have pretty much the same effect as (1).

Sentence (3) has no grammatical issues. *Nor* is used non-correlatively as a variant of *or* in negative contexts, and allows subject-auxiliary inversion in which case it is no longer replaceable by *or* (CaGEL p1309). However, the meaning here is not quite the same as (1) because it loses the adjunct of manner, the sense of *in the same way*.

Sentence (4) is clearly grammatical, and very close in meaning to (1). *More* here is in modifier function, but the usual degree meaning has effectively been lost. We don’t interpret (4) as a comparison between the degree/extent to which fish can't live without water and that to which people can't live without air (CaGEL p1133). It can be restated without a degree modifier as:

> Fish can't live without water, just as people can't live without air.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed and helpful information.

Comment: I don't actually think that's the problem (although leaving out the second *live* does seem to fix the sentence). [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/so) has the example *just as bad money drives out good, so does bad art drive out the good*, which repeats *drive out* but sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with sentence 1 is that the *not* is in the wrong place.

A grammatically sound rephrasing is

> As fish are not able to live without water, so are people not able to live without air.

Now that we've identified what's wrong with the sentence, we can try doing the same thing with *can*:

> *As fish cannot live without water, so can people not live without air.

Unfortunately, this doesn't look correct to me. I think the problem is that we are so used to seeing *cannot* written as one word that it doesn't look right when we split it into two, as we are forced to do by this sentence. A similar sentence

> As Ben wouldn't eat his breakfast, so would Beth not eat her dinner,

sounds fine to me, while

> *As Ben wouldn't eat his breakfast, so wouldn't Beth eat her dinner,

sounds wrong.